# How do I get rid of this horizontal scrollbar in Chrome and Safari?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do i get rid of the horizontal scrollbar on this code: [codepen](http://codepen.io/aaronj1335/pen/agJth)? I'm seeing it in Safari and Chrome, but not Firefox.

I'm using bootstrap, and I've got roughly the following markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="messages span6 offset1">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class=timestamp>[2:22 PM]</td>
            <td>echo|</td>
            <td>zot: Got a paste or gist of the code?</td>
          </tr>
          <!-- many more rows… -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And styling:

```
.messages {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.messages .timestamp {
  min-width: 75px;
}
```

The problem seems to be the `min-width` constraint, but I need that to keep the first column from wrapping. I also need to limit the height of messages to 200 pixels. I can't set `overflow-x: hidden` on `.messages` because it'll cut off content.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't want to use overflow: hidden; ? Because that can fix it.

Comment: @ChrisFrank yeah that won't work because it cuts off the content and there's no way to see it.

Comment: Take a look at this jsFiddle from NGLN: You might be able to adapt it for your own needs. http://jsfiddle.net/DGmUK/

Comment: @ChrisFrank that doesn't seem to be the same at all -- it's not using a table, and i don't see how it would cause a horizontal scrollbar in the first place.

Comment: I traced this out at some length below, and I assume you've thought of it, but why does it have to be a table? You're not displaying tabular data, so why not do this with `div` elements instead? Is that something bootstrap forces you to do?

Comment: @ChrisKrycho i responded to your answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:-

Use `word-break` on the last column to avoid it cut off.

[word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fword-break)

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rGAdP/)

```
.messages {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    
}
.messages .timestamp {
    min-width: 75px;
}
.messages td:nth-child(3) {
    word-break:break-all; /* or use word-break:normal; if you don't want to get the word cut in between*/
   
}
```

This will adjust the word-break based on the width available, without hiding the contents.

Comment: `word-break: break-all` breaks at any character, that won't work, but `word-break: break-word` seems to work. BUT, it doesn't seem to be standardized. any idea what's up with that?

Comment: You can use normal too. I mean main thing is using word-break and see if it reolves your issue, you can use which ever option of it.

Comment: Also , there is no break-word. it is normal. See the documentation link in my answer for the options.

Comment: @aaronstacy IS this close to what you are looking for?

Comment: this may be what i want -- none of the standardized values for `word-break` work (`break-all` breaks in the middle of words, `break-normal` doesn't get rid of the scrollbar). but if i use the non-standard `break-word` value, it solves the problem in Safari and Chrome, and doesn't seem to cause issues in FF. i'm looking at it some more, and if no better solutions come up i may end up going with this one.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following css:

```
.messages {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.messages .timestamp {
  min-width: 75px;
}
```

Comment: that won't work because it'll cut off the content that's hidden under the horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the height property for .messages to "auto" instead of 200px.

Comment: i actually want to limit the height of .messages, so i can't remove that constraint. i'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the width of the table by changing its span6 to a span7, or use a span class to force a width on the message tds that is consistent with the Twitter bootstrap grid structure context.

I couldn't tell you exactly why this is necessary; I actually don't know much about how tables get laid out. But this seems like a solution you could deploy.

Answer (score 0):

A completely alternate thought: why are you using tables to do this? You're not laying out tabular data; you have some semantically related pieces, but they're not tabular in their relationship. Given that, you're breaking one of the cardinal rules: don't use tables for layout! It looks to me like you could probably make this work much more sensibly using `div` elements, using either `float` or `inline-block` with specified widths on them. In that case, your markup would look something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="messages span6 offset1">
      <div class="message">
        <span class="timestamp">[2:22 PM]</div>
        <span class="author">echo|</div>
        <span class="messageContent">zot: Got a paste or gist of the code?</div>
      </div>
      <!-- many more rows… -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, your CSS would be fairly straightforward, since you've defined the `width` value for the `span6` (I looked at the actual CSS on the CodePen):

```css
.message {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.timestamp, .author, .messageContent {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.timestamp, .author {
    width: 75px;
}

.messageContent {
    400px; /* You'd obviously need to tweak this down to account for any padding */
}
```

You shouldn't have the nasty overflow problems, and the divs should fill up their heights in perfectly normal ways. You can also bound them. And there's no overflow issue anymore.

(Perhaps you're where you are because it's something that bootstrap defaults to, in which case: UGH. Break it, or do whatever is necessary to get away from using tables for layout. It will always, always be more pain than it's worth, and it's unsemantic to boot.)

Comment: i want the names to all be the same width, and i don't want that to any wider than the widest name. `<table>` seems like an elegant solution, no? when you say this isn't "tabular data", what are you basing that on? in fact each row corresponds to a row in a *data* base *table*. so i disagree. and when you say the `<table>` is unsemantic, what is that based on? web crawlers and screen readers (the reasons we care about semantic markup) just see a bunch of `<div>`'s in your solution. so once again i'd have to disagree.

Comment: @aaronstacy Under that argument, *everything* stored as rows in a database table should be represented as tables, right? Like blog posts! Obviously that's not right. The *reason* you chose tables is that you want the names to be the same width, and none wider than the widest… this is a classic example of using tables for layout because the way browsers render them happens to coincide with what you're looking for. Use `span` elements instead of `div`s if it makes you happier. Then pick a sane width for the username and call it a day. Separation of concerns is worth it.

Comment: @aaronstacy Also, depending on what your browser support level is, you may be able to use `display: table` on the box, which gives you the visual results you're looking for while still keeping the presentation of content separate from the layout.

Comment: `display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` will you give you a lot more flexibility if you want to put your site on mobile devices, too. You might find you'd rather put the username just below the timestamp instead of to the right, for example.

You can certainly force all username-class cells to share the same width, that's just done in CSS.

Comment: @iconmaster how does `display:table/table-row/table-cell` give me more flexibility on mobile devices? do mobile devices not support `<table>` elements?

Comment: @ChrisKrycho you haven't answered any of my questions. 1: what makes you say this is not tablular data? 2: how are a bunch of divs more semantic than a `<table>`?

Comment: @aaronstacy If you use a box with `display: table` in general, you can *choose* not to display as a table on a mobile device if that makes sense; you can't with an actual `<table>` element. My argument is that if the data is not *essentially* tabular—i.e., it is straightforward to think of non-tabular ways to lay it out (as is the case here)—then it's not actually tabular. Some of this admittedly comes down to personal taste, but I only use tables for *data*, for things where changing the layout hides or changes the basic nature of the relationship. That doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: @aaronstacy In fact, I'd say the question of whether you *can* re-layout something for e.g. mobile without losing semantic coherency tells you whether it's really tabular or not. If it's really a table—not just for presentation, but semantically—you can't just make an element stop being an independent column and have it make sense (short of just hiding it). You want the table to still be comprehensible as an entity, even if that requires horizontal scrolling or some such. When you're only using a tabular *layout* for non-tabular, you can readily change it when necessary—as is the case here.

Comment: @aaronstacy That's a lot of words, but it's why I think `<div>`s or `<span>`s are more semantic *in this case*: because the content you're displaying isn't intrinsically tabular. It could be laid out all sorts of ways and still make sense. Tabular data isn't like that: the relationships between rows and columns *define* the data. Note that none of this is to say that nested `<div>` and `<span>` elements is particularly lovely or elegant. Just that it represents the content more accurately in my view.

Comment: @ChrisKrycho your argument seems to be that because my data could be laid out without a table, it should be laid out without a table. and the only way this is possible (based on the specifications i listed in the first comment) is either setting css display properties to `display: table/table-row/table-cell` (essentially making divs into non-semantic tables), or using javascript to set the equal column widths. is that correct?

Comment: On why you shouldn't use tables, essentially yes. On the rest, that's true *if* you want table-style layout (which is basically the specs you laid out). Otherwise, there's no particular reason you have to do it with `display: table`; just pick a width for your `<div>` or `<span>` elements and call it a day. Assuming a bounded container, you have to set a `max-width` or the equivalent anyway; there's no reason not to just set a width (at least, not that I can see).

Comment: @ChrisKrycho if you just specify a width, long names could be cut off. i don't want that.

Comment: @aaronstacy That's a fair point. It seems like you'll inevitably run into space constraints at some point if your main container is bounded, though? I'd still lean toward `display: table` because it lets you change presentation as desired (e.g. for the mobile view I suggested above). Obviously I'm something of a purist, though; I understand why tables are tempting here, even if I ultimately disagree.